# Where can I save code when writing a CRUD UI in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, crud

I am trying to write an **efficient** CRUD UI for (lists of) objects of different classes that has

- one Facelets page to view and delete objects from a specified list and initiate edit or create on next page
- one Facelets page to edit an object or create a new one to be saved to previous pages list

But trying to reuse beans or Facelets pages I always get stuck at certain points. And although they do basically the same, I get the impression, that for **every class**, that I want to do CRUD-operations on, I need

- the both above mentioned Facelet pages
- a backing bean for the actions

I suppose this must be a well known problem. Is there a way to save code and not basically repeating oneself when it comes to CRUD?
I do not like the idea of using a generator, too, as that would still lead to a lot of repeated code that is hard to maintain.